# bouncing image help code not worgking outside jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use this bit of jQuery in a web application.  It seems to be working in jsfiddle, but not when implemented in my application.  Here is my code:

```
$('.myimage').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).effect('bounce',500);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jiggans/JJtsL/) is my jsfiddle.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "style3.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.effects.bounce.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="myimage" src ="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3513354941 /24aaffa670e634a7da9a087bfa83abe6.png">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.myimage').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).effect('bounce', 500);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function() { [your code] });`

Comment: jsFiddle has options on the left menu that automatically wrap it in the document.ready event handler. When you move out of jsFiddle you have to do this yourself

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you code in [$(document).ready(function () {](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myimage').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).effect('bounce', 500);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/JJtsL/1/)

asn don't forget to add `jQuery library` file

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myimage').mouseenter(
            function () {
                $(this).effect('bounce', 500);
    });
});
```

it needs to be in a document ready.

Also - just be weary that in your jsfiddle your image moves up another 30-40 px after a few times